# multiple nested Dropdown in materialize. popup in left or side of UL

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

i have materialize which looks like this....

```
<ul id="dropDownFacultyList" class="dropdown-content" >
            <li><a href="#">Wart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dart</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#" >Fart</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="dropDownGoaList">
            Goa Campus</a>
            <ul style="overflow: visible;" id="dropDownGoaList" class="dropdown-content sub-menu" style="left:0px">
                <li><a href="#">Deal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Meal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kill</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bill</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sill</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" >Neal</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

the sub menu works but popups in down the gutter

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and what have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

use top and bottom attribute if you are using absolute position to drop down